# Function.prototype.call doesn't work inside higher order functions and/or arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, this, higher-order-functions, arrow-functions

I try to use higher order functions (map, find, filter, reduce, etc) on an array of objects. In the callback I need to use a function inside of those objects, with the correct 'this' argument. Something like this:

```js
const something = [
  {
    x: 42,
    f: y => this.x + y
  },
  {
    x: 13,
    f: y => this.x - y
  }
]

const result = something.map(obj => obj.f.call(obj, 10));
```

I expected result to be [52, 3], but I've got this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Could you help me

- understand what happened here
- forward 'this' inside my function?

Thanks!

Comment: Arrow functions don't have a `this` of their own. They use the one from the outer scope, like it would with a variable that wasn't declared directly in the function. That's part of the point of arrow functions.

Comment: Also, you don't need `obj.f.call(obj, 10)`. You can just do `obj.f(10)` and it's exactly the same.

Comment: ...so if you need `this`, use traditional function syntax. `f: function(y) { return this.x + y }`

Comment: Thanks! It's a highly simplified example, I need to use `this`. I'll go with the traditional syntax.